# how to check three button conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

I am having three button image, I want to check the conditions between them. when I click the button 1 means background image change to blue colour. at the same time I click the button 1 it will move to normal state white colour. Same for another two buttons.For that process i am using this code. `[tempBtn setSelected:! tempBtn.selected];`

```
ButtonImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lblue.png"];
ButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"l.png"];
button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 27, 36, 36);
[button1 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button1.tag = 1;
[button1 setBackgroundImage:ButtonImageSelected
                   forState:UIControlStateSelected];
button1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[button1 addTarget:self
              action:@selector(button1Selector:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button1];
```

Another two buttons are same as button 1.

My condition is: when button 1 is clicked means button 3 should not change. when button 3 is clicked means button 1 should not change.button 2 can select in both the condition.I am using below code to check the conditions but its not working correct.

```
- (void)select_id:(UIButton *)tempBtn {
  if (tempBtn.tag == 1) {
    button3.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [tempBtn setSelected:!tempBtn.selected];
  } else if (tempBtn.tag == 3) {
    button1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [tempBtn setSelected:!tempBtn.selected];
  }
}
```

help me to how to check the conditions.In the above method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to accomplish is to have each button change states as you press them. Once you have defined your buttons, this is how you can ensure they alternate images for each state.

**Alternating Images Based on Button Presses**

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 1:
            if ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(button1.imageView.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"default1. png"])]) {
                [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            } else {
                [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(button2.imageView.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"default2. png"])]) {
                [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            } else {
                [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(button3.imageView.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"default3.png"])]) {
                [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            } else {
                [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Note:** make sure you add the action to each button, and change the names of the images

---

**Adding the Actions to Each Button**

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

---

Ensure you have done the following:

1. Added action to each button
2. Tagged each button accordingly
3. Set the initial images of each button to match the condition

Comment: I have edited the answer; it turns out the condition was not comparing the images properly. It has been updated and fixed. Make sure you follow all the steps before you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Before that make sure the tags are proper for every button

```
- (void)select_id:(UIButton *)tempBtn {
  if (tempBtn.tag == 1) {
    button3.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [tempBtn setSelected:!tempBtn.selected];
  } else if (tempBtn.tag == 3) {
    button1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [tempBtn setSelected:!tempBtn.selected];
  }
  else{
     button1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     button2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [tempBtn setSelected:!tempBtn.selected];


  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, in this code all the button are changing to blue.its not working help me bro.

Comment: your question is not very clear. Do you want only one blue button or zero blue buttons always. or something else.

Comment: changing colour is correct, but conditions is wrong, when i select button 1 means button 3 should not change. but button 3 is changing. when button 3 is selected means button 1 should not change. for me all the buttons are change when i select.